# Is sanyāsaṃ prohibited in Kaliyuga?

Tags: kali-yuga, dharma-shastras, smriti, sanyasi

Recently I have seen a video in which an elderly man says sanyāsaṃ is prohibited in Kali yuga. His statement is as follows:

> Aśvamedha, Gomedha, **sanyāsaṃ**, offering meat to manes, Begetting children after consuming alcohol should be given up in Kaliyuga.

- What is the sanskrit verse? Which smriti has this statement?
- Why is it said sanyāsaṃ should be given up in Kaliyuga?
- Are there any exceptions for the statement because we have many great acharyas who are sanyāsis' ?

Comment: [This Page](http://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/adi/17/16) says Brahma Vaivarta Purana Krishna Janma Khanda 185.180 is the above verse. But Krishna Janma Khanda has only 133 Chapters. So, i think this is interpolation.

Comment: Sanyasam is not prohibited in any Yuga as it is prescribed by Upanishads. See Jabala Upanishad.

Comment: @UdayKrishna That's why I posted a question . Together?!! How? Could you please elaborate it in answer field?

Answer (score 7):

[Verse 4.115 - Verses 112b,113a](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n1619/mode/1up?view=theater), Kṛṣṇa-janma-khaṇḍa, Brahma Vaivarta Purāṇa

> asvamedham gavalambham sannyasam palapaitrkam devarena sutopattim kalau panca vivarjayet
>
> Five things are forbidden in the age of Kali – horse-sacrifice, cow-sacrifice, **acceptance of sannyasa**, offering flesh to the forefathers and begetting a child in the womb of the wife of one’s elder brother.

Comment: The numbering of the verse is not correct. You can remove that.

Comment: Krishna janma khanda has only 133 chapters from sources i know. Do you have BvP with other chapters?

Comment: I have updated your answer with correct verses from the Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa, which you might have copied wrongly. Feel free to roll back the edit if you disagree. :) @Lakhi

Comment: Do you know, which kind of saṁnyāsa is being talked about here?

Answer (score 5):

From the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) we get the following list of acts that are considered as "Nishiddhas" or prohibited in Kali Yuga.

> **Kali Yuga Nishiddhas**:
>
> The following are the avoidable and unnecessary acts of Kali Yuga viz.
>   Samudra Yatra, carrying of Kamandulu to misdirect the Public ,
>   remarriages, begetting children from husband’s brothers; **Go Vadha;
>   Mamsa Bhakshana at Shraddhas;** performing vivaha to a physically immature girl; Chira kaala Brahmacharitwa; Naramedha **Ashwamedha Gomedha**
>   Yagna; Madya Paana, Abhakshya Bhakshana, Apeya paana, Agamyaagamana
>   orcwandering aimlesly Rahasya Prayascittha, Devata Puja and Pashubali
>   for evil ends; Kula Bhrashtata; Extreme Profiteering and narrow
>   mindedness.

So,some things mentioned  in the sloka in your question,like gomedha,aswamedha,offering meat to manes,etc are indeed prohibited in kali yuga but not Sannyasa.

Comment: +1 for this answer, May i know the main source of information in the given book is from ?

Comment: @Rishi The book quotes from Smritis and Puranas..In this case the original source must be some Puranas(my guess)..

Comment: Are you familiar with where it occurs in the actual dharma nibandha Dharmasindhu?

Comment: No I am only quoting from the book "Essence of Dharma Sindhu" .. I have not read the original work @Bingming

Comment: I see. Thanks. I just found it. It's from the ending sections of Pūrvārdha of 3rd pariccheda. https://archive.org/details/DharmaSindhuRajvaidyaRaviduttaShastry/page/n559/mode/2up?view=theater Although, it's not explicitly said that saṁnyāsa is prohibited, but vānaprastha is prohibited. This implies that karma saṁnyāsa is prohibited too. As per Nāradaparivrājakopaniṣat (5th upadeśa), karmasaṁnyāsa is that saṁnyāsa, which one takes, after the completing the prev. 3 āśramas.

Comment: I have covered this, in my answer.

Comment: Ok just now I have seen your answer @Bingming

Answer (score 2):

Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa (4.115.112b-113a) mentions 5 kaliyuganiṣiddha karmas -

> aśvamedham gavālabbhaṁ saṁnyāsaṁ palapaitr̥kam // 
> devareṇa sutotpati kalau pañca vivarjayet /

Saṁnyāsa is also mentioned under the Kaliyuga niṣiddhas, which is pretty strange. We clearly know that saṁnyāsa is present in Kaliyuga, and great śiṣṭa ācāryas such as Rāmānuja, Madhva, Śaṅkara Bhagavatapāda, etc. took saṁnyāsa. So, clearly this isn't a prohibition of saṁnyāsa, as a whole. 
It's most likely a prohibition of a specific kind of saṁnyāsa. Some online articles by Gauḍīyas 
(such as [a](https://www.rupanugabhajanashram.com/writings/krishna-talk-articles/swami-bv-giri/is-sannyasa-forbidden-in-kali-yuga/)
; [b](https://harmonist.us/2010/01/sannyasa-in-kali-yuga/))  in recent times, take the saṁnyāśa in above quoted śloka to mean karmasaṁnyāsa.

As per Kūrma Purāṇa (1.2.80), the bhikṣu who does relentless yogābhyāsa, remains steady on mokṣamārga, conquers over indriyas, and perseveres for attainment of jñāna, is 'pārameṣṭhika'. 
Śloka [(82)](https://archive.org/details/kurma-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n31/mode/2up?view=theater) mentions three kinds of pārameṣṭhika, viz. jñānasaṁnyāsin, vedasaṁnyāsin, & karmasaṁnyāsin.
But the succeeding ślokas don't explain three saṁnyāsins.

> yogābhāsarato nityamārurukṣurjitendriyaḥ / 
> jñānāya vartate bhikṣuḥ procyate pārameṣṭhikaḥ // (80) 
> jñānasaṁnyāsinaḥ kecidvedasaṁnyāsino'pare / 
> karmasaṁnyāsinaḥ kecit trividhāḥ pārameṣṭhikāḥ // (82)

As per 'common' usage of karmasaṁnyāsa, we know that it refers to karmayoga, propounded by Kr̥ṣṇa, in Bhagavad Gītā.  So, *that* karma saṁnyāsa isn't a niṣiddha kriyā for Kaliyuga.   Nāradaparivrājakopaniṣat [(5.6)](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook108UpanishadsPart1brahmaVidyaKhanadaPt.ShriramSharmaAcharya/page/n141/mode/2up?view=theater) gives a def. of karmasaṁnyāsin. Karmasaṁnyāsin is the person (even if he has abhāva of vairāgya), who takes saṁnyāsa, after living through first three āśramas (brahmacarya, gr̥hastha, & vānaprastha).

> brahmacaryaṁ samāpya gr̥hī bhūtvā vānaprasthāśramametya vairāgyabhāve'pyāśramakramānusāreṇa yaḥ saṁnyasyati sa karmasaṁnyāsī //

So, perhaps this is the kind of saṁnyāsa, which Gauḍīyas are referring to. Unfortunately, they don't provide any śāstriya support afaik, for taking this stance.
But there is an observation, we can work with, that is the lack of vānaprasthīs, since more than a 100 yrs. We don't see anyone taking vānaprastha āśrama. People usually go directly to saṁnyāsa āśrama after gr̥hastha or brahmacarya, but are rarely seen taking karmasaṁnyāsa (as defined in Nāradaparivrājakopaniṣat). 
Is vānaprastha niṣiddha in Kaliyuga?

The famous dharmanibandha 'Dharmasindhu' by Kāśīnātha Upādhyāya ([1](https://archive.org/details/DHARMASINDHU/page/n309/mode/2up?view=theater) ; [2](https://archive.org/details/DharmaSindhuRajvaidyaRaviduttaShastry/page/n559/mode/2up?view=theater) ; [3](https://archive.org/details/vndI_dharma-sindhu-of-kashinath-upadhyay-with-bhasha-tika-by-mihir-chandra-khemraj/page/n535/mode/2up?view=theater)), also mentions the niṣiddhakarmas (>5) for Kaliyuga, and these are as follows:

> samudrayātrā (for dvijas), bearing kamaṇḍalu (to misdirect public),
> dvija having vivāha with those of other varṇas, niyoga with devara,
> paśubali at madhuparka, offering & bhakṣaṇa of māṁsa at śrāddha,
> entering vānaprastha āśrama, re-kanyā-dāna of one's kanyā (who's
> akṣatyoni) to someone else, being in brahmacarya for too long
> (dīrgha-kālaṁ), naramedha, aśvamedha, mahāprasthāna, gomedha, doing
> prāyaścitta of mahāpāpa that culminates in death, madyapāna (including
> that in yajñas such sautrāmaṇi, etc.), following the śāstras of
> vāmācāra on the issue of madyapāna, etc. (because madyapāna, etc. is
> prohibited by śiṣṭas in both Pūrva & Uttara Mīmāṁsā), having putras
> other than aurasa or dattaka/kanīna (*there are 12 kinds of sons, as
> per śāśtras, and 10 of these are niṣiddha in Kaliyuga. But, as per
> Kaustubha grantha, apart from aurasa & kanīna, svayaṁdatta/sahoḍhaja
> is also yogya in Kaliyuga, and the rest of 9 kinds of sons are
> niṣiddha*), and removing a person from deśa, grāma, kula or jāti upon
> their committing mahāpāpa (such as Brahmahatyā), etc.

Since, vānaprastha comes under kalivarjya, so karmasaṁnyāsa (as defined in Nāradaparivrājakopaniṣat) is automatically also a Kaliyuga niṣiddhakarma.