# What are the duties of Dvija-Bandhus?

Tags: dharma, varna, yagnopavitam, upanayanam, dvija

According to the book ["Hindu Dharma" by Sri Sri Chandrashekarendra Saraswati](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/chap12.htm):

> **If the Gayatri has not been chanted for three generations in the
>   family of a Brahmin, its members lose caste (they cease to be
>   Brahmins).** The quarter where such Brahmins live cannot be called an
>   "agrahara". It is perhaps not yet three generations since Brahmins
>   gave up the Gayatri. So they still may be called Brahmins.
>
> In the same way if the Brahmin family has not performed sacrifices for
>   three generations its members will be called "Durbrahmanas",
>   degenerate Brahmins. Even though degenerate the label "Brahmin" sticks
>   to them. There are prayascittas (expiatory rites) by means of which
>   the corrupted Brahmins will be remade true Brahmins. **But there is no
>   such hope for a Brahmin in whose family Gayatri has not been chanted
>   for three generations. A member of such a family ceases altogether to
>   be a Brahmin and cannot be made one again. He is just a "Brahmana-
>   bandhu", a kin or a friend of Brahmins. The same rule applies to
>   Ksatriyas and Vaisyas with regard to the Gayatri mantra; they become
>   "ksatriya-bandhus" and "Vaisya-bandhus" respectively.**

Now, technically I am a Kshatriya-bandhu since upanayana hasn't taken place in my family for more than three generations. So what are the duties prescribed for me? What about Brahmana-Bandhus and Vaishya-Bandhus?

**Edit:** A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada in his commentary to Srimad-Bhagavatam 1.12.35, equates Brahmana-Bandhus to Shudras:

> Simply taking birth in the family of a brāhmaṇa does not make one qualified to perform yajñas. One must be twice-born by proper training and initiation from the bona fide ācārya. **The once-born scions of brāhmaṇa families are equal with the once-born śūdras, and such brahma-bandhus, or unqualified once-born scions, must be rejected for any purpose of religious or Vedic function.** Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa was entrusted to look after this arrangement, and perfect as He is, He caused the yajñas to be performed by the bona fide twice-born brāhmaṇas for successful execution.
>   The unworthy sons of the royal orders are called kṣatra-bandhavas, as the unworthy sons of the brāhmaṇas are called dvija-bandhus or brahma-bandhus.

Does that mean Dvija-Bandhus have the same duties as Shudras? Should they be treated as Shudras as well or as the Varna they are born into?

Comment: Same here. I'm also Kshatriya Bandhu.

Comment: @Tamas. Sad right? :)

Comment: Yes, it's sad. And it's highly unlikely to compensate the loss. Btw, I'm in 3rd generation.

Comment: @Tamas. But I guess you have crossed the required age.

Comment: Well, I am out of rituals mode. :)

Comment: @Tamas 3rd generation can undergo I think so

Comment: @Parikshitha Last age is 13 for Kshatriya I think.

Comment: @Tamas for Brahmins it is 16, 

Comment: So, for Kshatriyas last age is 22 @Tamas

Comment: as the word bandhu implies, it is our duty to help. as brahma-bandhu, we can help brahmins by donating money to veda pata shala and temples, and by honoring them due to their commitment to self-sacrifice through study and sense-control. As kshatriya bandhu, we can help kshatriyas by donating money to army veterans and their families. and by respecting them due to their commitment to self-sacrifice through courage and fighting. How many people make fun of brahmanas in movies and sardarji jokes in internet. At least, we can stop doing that.

Comment: Um, is this a trick question? @commonman

Comment: Just like everyone knows. My parents say our family is Kshatriya. @commonman

Comment: Oh okay. I wasn't aware of that. We're Kayasthas though. @commonman

Comment: Well, according to Chandrashekararendra Saraswati, I won't be eligible for prayaschitta even because no Upanayana has been done in my family for over three generations. So should I be considered a Shudra? @commonman

Comment: Sad  @commonman

Comment: Yes, that is true  @commonman