# Do Vedas forbid Sannyasa in Kali Yuga?

Tags: vedas, puranas, rig-veda, kali-yuga, sannyasa

Someone told me that Brahma-vaivarta Purana & Krsna-jnama Khanda have this verse:

asvamedham gavalambham sannyasam palapaitrkam
devarena sutopattim kalau panca vivarjayet

The above verse seems to mean: “Five things are forbidden in the age of Kali – horse-sacrifice, cow-sacrifice, acceptance of sannyasa, offering flesh to the forefathers and begetting a child in the womb of the wife of one’s elder brother.” Nevertheless, it's not known what Vedas say on this issue.

Comment: Do you want answer from Vedas only?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/is-sany%C4%81sa%E1%B9%83-prohibited-in-kaliyuga

Comment: Various puranas give different rules for different yugas. The yugas do not appear in the vedas. These various and often conflicting rules appear only in the puranas.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - By that logic, we should not study Brahma Sutras or Gita because they are not "Vedas". Smriti, Itihasa & Puranas are part and parcel of Vedas/Vedangas. All contradictions are  only 'apparent'. Those who have right knowledge know how to resolve them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sannyasa a Vedic way of life? Is it recommended by the Vedas, the ten authentic Upanishads or Grhyasutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32052/is-sannyasa-a-vedic-way-of-life-is-it-recommended-by-the-vedas-the-ten-authent)