Animal sacrifice prohibited in kaliyuga
Animal sacrifice prohibited in kaliyug
Because in kaliyug narial bali started
And no brahmin is pure

Not prohibited entirely but sacrifices of certain animals is prohibited as well as animal sacrifice in general for evil purposes  .. see this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16947
